# How to use iPhone with hotspot as a router/modem for entire home network

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, tethering, games

**Reason:** I recently moved from one house to another and my internet provider doesn't cover the new area. The other internet providers take over a month to supply me with a connection.
I have to work from home, I would like to watch Netflix and game on my PS4.

**Situation at this moment:** I bought a simcard with unlimited data. Put it in my iPhone and activated the hotspot. I can use this to watch Netflix and browse the internet on my Mac etc. I however cannot work from home or play PS4 with an open NAT type. This is (so I have read) because of my internet coming from a hotspot.

**Looking for:** Help to set up my macbook as a router or something like that to provide open NAT type.
Thanks so much in advance for any help given. I have searched for days but cannot find a way still.

Another example of someone with this issue and his progress is here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/6hklpx/help_iphone_usb_tether_to_ps4_using_mac_as_a/

Comment: Try going to `System Preferences` > `Sharing` > `Internet Sharing` and see if you have any options if you are using your iPhone's internet via USB.